# Which is more efficient smallint or character(10)?

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, memory-efficient

I'm storing 5000 books in a table, the table contains titles, authors, years and ISBN.
Now I'm making a table for reviews of the books.
Which would be more efficient or just the better way to do it, create a column for ids in the books' table and use that id to store reviews of the books in the reviews table, or use the books' ISBN number which is stored as a character(10)?

When I say "efficient" I mean "conserving storage space".

Comment: Why does it matter with only 5000 books?

Comment: Because there will be more in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that adding an artificial `smallint` primary key would be cheaper in terms of storage space, if the table is carefully designed.

A `smallint` takes 2 bytes, while a `character(10)` (which is, counter-intuitively, a `varlena`) containing ASCII characters, will consume 14 bytes.

In the table, the extra 2 bytes would be waste, but don't forget that you will have an index on the primary key column. So the indexed value will actually be stored twice: once in the table, once in the index.

For simplicity's sake, let's ignore tuple headers and other overhead.

- Using the ISBN as primary key will cost an extra 14 bytes per table row.
- Adding a `smallint` primary key will add two bytes to the table and two to the index, making a total of four added bytes.

So **adding a `smallint` primary key should save space**.

You should not ignore alignment issues. All data types are stored at memory addresses that are multiples of certain powers of two. This is required by the processors' architectures. A `smallint` typically has alignment 2, `character` has alignment 1, while for example `timestamp` has alignment 8.

So if your table is defined as

```
CREATE TABLE book (
   id smallint PRIMARY KEY,
   issue_time timestamp with time zone,
   isbn character(10)
);
```

Then the table data would look like this:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| | |X|X|X|X|X|X| | | | | | | | | ... (ISBN omitted)
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 id    padding     issue_time
```

The row is aligned at an 8-byte boundary, and the six bytes from the end if `id` to the beginning of `issue_time` will be empty “padding bytes”.

So to make the most of it, you'll have to consider in which order you define the columns.

**Why all this is not very relevant in reality:**

A table with 5000 or 10000 entries is tiny, no matter what.

Any though spent on optimizing space here is at best unnecessary micro-optimization.

But what may be a smart idea on the planning table can easily backfire later:
If – different from what you expect – you want to store 70000 books in the table, you will find that a `smallint` won't be enough, even if you allow negative `id`s. The pain you will have to endure when you have to change the data type of a primary key and all foreign keys that reference it in a live system will by far outweigh any pleasure you get from saving some 100 KB by clever optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

Usually - it depends. Operation over int type are pretty fast. Should be faster than on any character type. Type "char" is "varchar" in Postgres, and char(10) needs 11 bytes what is more than 4 for integer. On second hand isbn is mandatory field, and ids maybe optional - so table without ids can be smaller.

So int is more effective type for primary key than varchar. But on this day machines you need to do lot of complex operations with maybe more than 1M rows to find any visible differences.