# PostgreSQL: smaller timestamptz type?

Tags: postgresql, types, size

Timestamptz time is 8 bytes in PostgreSQL. Is there a way to get a 6 bytes timestamptz dropping some precision?

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: Why would you want that? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: @stickybit the actual problem is optimizing for size a big table. I'll make a separate question for that later if needed, but I think this is a good question on its own.

Answer (score 2):

6 bytes is pretty much out of the question, since there is no data type with that size.

With some contortions you could use a 4-byte `real` value:

```
CREATE CAST (timestamp AS bigint) WITHOUT FUNCTION;

SELECT (localtimestamp::bigint / 1000000 - 662774400)::real;

    float4    
--------------
 2.695969e+06
(1 row)
```

That would give you the time since 2021-01-01 00:00:00 with a precision of about a second (but of course for dates farther from that point, the precision will deteriorate).

But the whole exercise is pretty much pointless. Trying to save 2 or 4 bytes in such a way will not be a good idea:

- the space savings will be minimal; today, when you can have terabytes of storage with little effort, that seems pointless
- if you don't carefully arrange your table columns, you will lose the bytes you think you have won to [alignment issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58122257/6464308)
- using a number instead of a proper `timestamp` data type will make your queries more complicated and the results hard to interpret, and it will keep you from using [date arithmetic](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

For all these reasons, I would place this idea firmly in the realm of harmful micro-optimization.